# Usage of LIMIT shows error in mysql 5.7.32 version

Tags: mysql

This syntax is giving output in `server version : 10.3.27-MariaDb-cll-lve`, but has fetched error in `5.7.32`.
If `LIMIT` has been removed from query, it works. Can't we use `LIMIT` as this way in `5.7.32` - MySQL Community Server (GPL). ?

```
$sql = "
SELECT cat_frnt.rd
     , GROUP_CONCAT(nws.rd,'#@',nws.hdng,'#@',SUBSTR(nws.cntnt,1,1000) ORDER BY nws.rd DESC, nws.date DESC LIMIT 1) AS nws 
  FROM nws_cat 
  JOIN nws 
    ON nws.rd = nws_cat.nws 
  LEFT 
  JOIN cat_frnt 
    ON cat_frnt.rd = nws_cat.cat 
  LEFT 
  JOIN subcat 
    ON subcat.rd = nws_cat.subcat 
 GROUP 
    BY cat_frnt.rd
";
```

Comment: I think you've answered your own question

Comment: Incidentally, there's no merit in LEFT JOINING tables from which you select no columns

Comment: Please share more details, like the **exact** error message

Comment: Use SUBSTRING_INDEX over GROUP_CONCAT instead of non-legal LIMIT.

Comment: Just one of many ways mariadb is diverging from mysql.. BTW manual says limit was introduced in mariadb 10.3.3